# If X + Y is truncated normal and X and Y are identitically (but not independently) distributed? What is the distribution of X and Y?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $(aX + bY)$ be a truncated normal and assume $X,Y$ are both identically distributed (but necessarily NOT independent) what is the distribution of $X$ and $Y$? More importantly can the pdf of $X$ be written just in terms of $X$?

Is this known? Or have I just defined a new distribution?

Suppose in the case that $aX + bY$ is a standard normal singly truncated from the top at $\beta$ i.e. $aX + bY \le \beta$ then taking the limit as $b$ goes to 0 we must have 
$$aX \sim N(0,1)|aX < \beta$$
so from this I can intuitively deduce that
$$aX|bY ~ N(0,1)|aX <\beta - bY$$
and symmetrically
$$bY|aX ~ N(0,1)|bY <\beta - aX$$
so the distribution of one variable given the other is know to be just a truncated normal but it seems quite different to write out the pdf the unconditional distribution. Indeed, let $f(x)$ be the pdf of $X$ then

$$f(x) = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty f(x|y)f(y)\ dy$$
the right side also involves the $f$ so it looks pretty hard to solve?

Comment: How can you take the limit as $b \to 0$?  Do you mean that you have, not just the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $a X + b Y$ having the truncated normal distribution, but random variables $X(a,b)$ and $Y(a,b)$ defined for all $a$ and $b$?  How would that work when $a=b=0$?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, I doubt that there's much that can be said.  There are just too many ways to obtain $Z$ as the sum of $X$ and $Y$.  For example, here are some ways to get an arbitrary distribution as 
$Z = X + Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ identically distributed.  Let $B$ be Bernoulli($1/2$) and independent of $Z$.  Let $f$ be an arbitrary Borel function.
Let $X = B f(Z) + (1-B)(Z-f(Z))$ and $Y = B (Z - f(Z)) + (1-B) f(Z)$.